# How to create a pandas dataframe with a column as array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to create a dataframe with one of the column as a list or array
But an attempt to do so gives an error *'Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable'* Please support

```
  eg  data.loc[0,'emails']={'a@a.com','b@b.com'} =>error 
      data.loc[0,'emails']='a@a.com' =>No error
```

Data=>

```
> Name  | emails
  ___________________________  
> Judas |['j@a.com','x@y.com']
> Priest|['x@a.com','x@y.com','j@k.com']
```

This scenario could be one like trying to get only list of emails as a column from one of the columns which contains very long texts.

Comment: What was the attempt that produced that result?

Comment: Array-likes in DataFrame columns is often a bad idea, why do you want to do it?

Comment: I am trying to get list of words of interest from one of the columns which contains long text

Comment: Wouldn't the following structure be better? (Rows) `Judas, j@a.com | Judas, x@y.com | Priest, x@a.com | ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you assign a `list` like or `array` like value to the columns, the column should be considered as type `object`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Juda','Pri']})
df['Email']=''
df.Email=df.Email.astype(object)
df.loc[0,'Email']={'a@a.com','b@b.com'}
df
Out[511]: 
   Name               Email
0  Juda  {b@b.com, a@a.com}
1   Pri
```

Answer (score 0):

The question could be more clear, to be honest. Does this result in what you expect?

```
a = ["Judas" , ['j@a.com','x@y.com']]
b = ['Priest', ['x@a.com','x@y.com','j@k.com']]
df = pandas.DataFrame([a,b])
print(df)
```

gives:

```
            0                            1
0   Judas           [j@a.com, x@y.com]
1  Priest  [x@a.com, x@y.com, j@k.com]
```